How to revert Java 10 "use local varaible type inference" via save actions?
I checked out the Java 10 option of "use local variable type inference" (JEP 286), but I think it is terrible to replace all type information with just the keyword var - was so much better to know what type you're currently working on.
Is there an option to revert this over a bunch of projects via save actions?
Just un-checking that option in Eclipse settings is not working, I would have to change all variables by hand.
Addon:
We changed that 2 month ago and we add a lot of things since we did that. We can not just rollback that single change anymore. Further it is replaced in more then 50 projects.
So the option with source repo is not possible -> most of the changes which are done by save actions can be reverted with just deactivating that feature there -> this thing apparently not, so be careful.
Please avoid discussing about "var" is useful or not, there are different threads about that topic and we made our decision already based on 2 month experience.

Note that hover the mouse over the var will show the inferred type.

Can't you just revert the change using whatever version control system you're using?

You may be able to use "Replace With... > Local History" to go back to older versions of the files

Ok,I found finally a solution for that.
I had to use IntellyJ, but there is a free community version so not a big thing.
Further I had to change the following settings in intelliJs preferences.
Search for "type var", change java 10 settings to activate implicit type usage, activate warnings to highlight the findings

Scan all Projects that should be changed by clicking on one of the var declarations. There are extra options behind the ">" sign to scan the whole structure.:

Replace all findings in the context window below code:


No, there is not. Use source control next time.

We changed that 2 month ago and we add a lot of things since we did that. We can not just rollback that single change anymore. Further it is replaced in more then 50 projects all are development further. So the option with source repo is not possible, but thanks for the helpful answer and for voting.

The Save Action is there to help adopt and migrate to newer syntaxes. There's little to no demand for a feature to automate changes in the other direction. I suppose this wouldn't be considered a "useful" answer, but I doubt anyone will tell you otherwise.
